# Removing excessive dashes with OR regex

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to remove all excessive dashes from strings.

`StateFileRegexDashes = regexp.MustCompile(`--+?|^-+?|-+$`)`

The above regex seems to work for me on regex101, but not within my code.
I was thinking it could be because of the 'g|global modifier', but I assume that is solved by the 'All' part in `ReplaceAllString()`

Golang Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZR72gZEhZ_
Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/tUYHo1/1

**Edit**:
Problem was I was replacing everything with - dashes, where I actually wanted to remove prefixed and trailing dashes.

Instead of doing another regex, I'm just using `strings.Trim()` now.

```
var (
    StateFileRegex       = regexp.MustCompile(`[\/\?<>\\:\*\|":!\s.]`)
    StateFileRegexDashes = regexp.MustCompile(`--+`)
)

func hashBotStateFile(name string) string {
    lower := strings.ToLower(name)
    dashes := StateFileRegex.ReplaceAllString(lower, StateFileCharReplacer)
    singles := StateFileRegexDashes.ReplaceAllString(dashes, StateFileCharReplacer)
    trimmed := strings.Trim(singles, "-")
    return filepath.Join(StateFileFolder, fmt.Sprintf("%s.json", trimmed))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the leading/trailing `-` symbols, and shrink those inside the string. You need to split the dashes regex into

```
StateFileRegexDashes = regexp.MustCompile(`--+`)
StateFileRegexDashesRemove = regexp.MustCompile(`^-+|-+$`)
```

And then use something like

```
func hashBotStateFile(name string) string {
    lower := strings.ToLower(name)
    dashes := StateFileRegex.ReplaceAllString(lower, StateFileCharReplacer)
    trimmed := StateFileRegexDashes.ReplaceAllString(dashes, StateFileCharReplacer)
    final := StateFileRegexDashesRemove.ReplaceAllString(trimmed, "")
    return filepath.Join(StateFileFolder, fmt.Sprintf("%s.json", final))
}
```

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/sVJWXqOzdw)

Also, note that `--+?` at the end of the pattern will always match only 2 hyphens, you need to turn the lazy quantifiers into *greedy* ones.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Replace double dashes with dash, replace edge-dashes with nothing! Also good point about the greedy modifier!